# problem with dart-sdk from within flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I run flutter upgrade and and I got the following message

```
C:\Users\lenovo\IdeaProjects\simple>flutter upgrade
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 2.5.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 18116933e7 (3 weeks ago) • 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
Engine • revision d3ea636dc5
Tools • Dart 2.14.4
```

but when I try to upgrade the packages including the riverpod which has got to the stable release today

I got the following message

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.13.4.

    Because simple depends on flutter_riverpod >=1.0.0 which requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
    pub get failed (1; Because simple depends on flutter_riverpod >=1.0.0 which requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.)
```

I when check the dart sdk in the setting of the editor I'm currently using, the dart sdk is of version 2.13.4

anyone know how to fix this issue ??

Comment: I think you have two flutters installed but your path is pointing to the older one. I would suggest removing both of them and then reinstalling flutter would do the trick.

Comment: exactly it was the problem and it have been fixed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the versions, keep only the dependency names in pubspec.yaml . Then run flutter pub get. It will automatically download all compatible versions.